# npm does not support Node.js v8.17.0 WSL2

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, nvm

So I've been getting the below error. I know the ideal answer is to update but to update, would be a very substantial amount of work at this point, and we're only using this to compile our code locally. It would seem others have gotten this working within my company without issue, but I'm the only one on Windows 11 trying to do this through WSL (version 2 to be specific in the VM). Basically, this happens whenever I run an `npm` command. Whether it's `npm install` or `npm -v`, it comes up every single time.

I am using nvm v0.39.0 and Node v8.17.0 so the `npm` version "should be" 6.13.4 according to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/release/v8.17.0/). I have installed Node through `nvm` using `nvm install 8` and `nvm alias default 8`. I also have 12 installed but have ensured I'm switched to 8. I can't find anything

When I `nvm use 12` or `nvm use --lts`, I obviously get new errors that I'd have to work through (a big amount of work mostly in QA for clients, not going to get into extensive detail). Can anyone think of a way around this?

It's not like an app where it's constantly running and we need the latest and greatest. It's only for compiling code during the development and deployment process.

```
npm does not support Node.js v8.17.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of the node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
/home/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:32
  #unloaded = false
  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at module.exports (/home/<user>/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:22:15)
```

---

## UPDATE

I tried to duplicate the issue on my Linux PopOS machine, and these are the steps I took to replicate it (So maybe not Windows specific, but maybe Linux, since the other environment was in WSL 2 Ubuntu dist?):

Install nvm:

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash`

Install the versions we support and set the default:

`nvm install 8`

`nvm alias default 8`

`nvm install 12`

`nvm use 8`

`npm login --registry=https://example.com/` (not disclosing this on stackoverflow)

**At this point I did an `npm -v` and it returned v6.13.4.**

Install a few things we know we'll need for our projects, in each version:

`nvm use 8 && npm install -g npm && npm install -g grunt-cli gulp-cli`

**It broke and started giving the error again after the above command.**

Comment: What version of npm do you have installed?

Comment: @Joe I cannot even use `npm -v` as stated when I'm on Node version 8, but according to this https://nodejs.org/es/blog/release/v8.17.0/ it is NPM version 6.13.4 that is packaged with the version of Node I am trying to use. I have confirmed with my colleague on Mac that he is using this as well.

Comment: @Joe I've updated the ticket with further details. Not sure if you have any answers.

Comment: Does `npm install -g npm@6` to install npm 6 specifically work?  Your command above will install latest npm, which is not really compatible with that old a version of node any more.

Comment: @Joe It would seem this fixed it. Am still facing some other weird Windows stuff, but they are their own questions. If you post an answer I'll gratefully accept it from my side. Thank you so much!